# algebra direct connect pell eqn soln $(p_{nk},q_{nk})$ with $(p_n + q_n\sqrt{D})^k$

Tags: continued-fractions, pell-type-equations

Just edited the posted question to correct a dead link to one of the pdf files.

---

Apologies if this question has been asked before - there are many "pell" entries
in this forum.

**Given:** 
(a) $\;D \in \mathbb{Z^+}\;$ is not a perfect square. 
(b) The continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{D}\;$ is
$\;[a_1, \overline{a_2, \cdots, a_n, 2a_1}].$ 
(c) Coprime $\;\frac{p_r}{q_r}\;$ denotes the $r^{th}$ convergent of $\sqrt{D}.$ 
(d) $\;\forall k \in \mathbb{Z^+}, \;(P_k,Q_k)$ is defined by
$\;(p_n + q_n\sqrt{D})^k = P_k + Q_k\sqrt{D}.$

**To prove:** (e) $\;\forall k \in \mathbb{Z^+},$
$\;(p_{nk},q_{nk}) = (P_k, Q_k).$

**My research:** Let $E_1$ denote the pell equation $\;x^2 - Dy^2 = \pm 1.\;$
I reviewed pages 1-7 (through theorem 1.19) of [pdf-1](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Yang.pdf),
chapter 1 (only) of [pdf-2](https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-497500429547.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/a06_cont_frac_Khinchin.pdf), this [pdf-3](http://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Esohum/ma330/files/Continued%20Fractions.pdf), and
[html-4](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/contfrac/pell.html).  From these references, I concluded:

(1) $\;\{(p_n,q_n), (p_{2n},q_{2n}), (p_{3n},q_{3n}), \cdots \}\;$ is the
complete set of all positive integer solutions to $E_1.$

(2) $\;\{(P_1,Q_1), (P_2,Q_2), (P_3,Q_3), \cdots \}\;$ is **also** the
complete set of all positive integer solutions to $E_1.$

(3) The 4 sequences $\;\{p_n, p_{2n}, p_{3n}, \cdots \},
\;\{q_n, q_{2n}, q_{3n}, \cdots \},
\;\{P_1, P_2, P_3, \cdots \},\;$ and $\;\{Q_1, Q_2, Q_3, \cdots \}\;$
are **each strictly increasing.**

From these conclusions I **indirectly deduced** result (e) above.  However, as
I have elaborated in my Partial Work section (below), I would like to establish this
result directly, through algebra.

**Partial Work:** I decided to attempt to algebraically demonstrate that 
coprime $\;(p_{2n}, q_{2n}) = ([{p_n}^2 + D{q_n}^2], 2p_nq_n) = (P_2, Q_2).\;$ 
If successful, I then hoped to find a pattern in the demonstration that would allow
me to show that 
$[F_1]\;\; \forall k\in\mathbb{Z^+}, 
\;(p_{n(k+1)}, q_{n(k+1)}) = (p_{nk}p_n + Dq_{nk}q_n, p_{nk}q_n + q_{nk}p_n).\;$ 
This would allow me to inductively conclude result (e) above.

$a_1 = $ the floor of $\sqrt{D}.$ 
Let $A$ denote the continued fraction $\;[a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n] = \frac{p_n}{q_n}.$ 
Let $B$ denote the continued fraction $\;[2a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n].$

Then, $\;B = a_1 + \frac{p_n}{q_n}\;$ and 
$\;\frac{p_{2n}}{q_{2n}} = \;$ the continued fraction represented by
$\;[A, B].$ 
I can now generate 2 **non-linear** equations ($F_2$ and $F_3,$ below)
for $\;p_{2n}, q_{2n}\;$ 
that depend on the computation of coprime $p_{n-1}$ and $q_{n-1}.$ 
I may have to give special consideration for when $\;n=1\;$
(e.g. $\sqrt{2} = [1, \overline{2}]$), 
since then $(p_{n-1}, q_{n-1}) = \;$ the *artificially contrived* $(1, 0).$

$[F_2]\;\; \dfrac{Bp_n + p_{n-1}}{Bq_n + q_{n-1}} = \;$ the *ratio* $\dfrac{p_{2n}}{q_{2n}}.$ 
$[F_3]\;\; {p_{2n}}^2 - D{q_{2n}}^2 = (-1)^{2n} = 1.$

Assuming that $p_{2n}$ and $q_{2n}$ are each expressed in terms of
$\;p_n, q_n, p_{n-1}, q_{n-1}, a_1\;$ and $\;D,\;$ 
I now have to compute $p_{n-1}$ and $q_{n-1}$ in terms of
$\;p_n, q_n, a_1\;$ and $\;D.\;$

Let $\beta $ denote $[\overline{2a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n}] = a_1 + \sqrt{D}.$ 
Then $\sqrt{D}$ may be represented by the continued fraction $\;[A,\beta].$ 
Therefore, (I suspect that) the following two equations will generate unique
values for $p_{n-1}$ and $q_{n-1}:$

$[F_4]\;\; \dfrac{\beta p_n + p_{n-1}}{\beta q_n + q_{n-1}} = \sqrt{D}.$ 
$[F_5]\;\; p_nq_{n-1} - q_np_{n-1} = (-1)^n\;$ 
(since the first element of the continued fraction is $a_1,$ rather than $a_0$).

Unfortunately, $F_2, F_3, F_4,\;$ and $F_5\;$ seem very ugly to me, and there is
no way to predict the challenges in $F_1.$  I guess that it is not suprising that
an *indirect* proof was chosen for the last theorem in [html-4](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/contfrac/pell.html).

Anyway, has any professional mathematician wrestled with this?  For example,
would any of the later chapters in Khinchin's [pdf-2](https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-497500429547.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/a06_cont_frac_Khinchin.pdf) be pertinent?  Alternatively, does anyone have any ideas about making the attack less
crude?

My knowledge of field theory is fairly weak, so please be merciful.

Comment: Never wrong if it's about pell equations

Answer (score 2):

I just had insights that facilitated the proof.

**Given:** 
(a) $\;D \in \mathbb{Z^+}\;$ is not a perfect square.
(b) The continued fraction expansion of $\;\sqrt{D}\;$ is 
    $\;[a_1, \overline{a_2, \cdots, a_n, 2a_1}].$ 
(c) Coprime $\;\frac{p_r}{q_r}\;$ denotes the $r^{th}$ 
    convergent of $\sqrt{D}.$ 
(d) $\;\forall k \in \mathbb{Z^+}, \;(P_k,Q_k)$ is defined by 
    $\;(p_n + q_n\sqrt{D})^k = P_k + Q_k\sqrt{D}.$

**To prove:** $\;\;$ (e) $\;\forall k \in \mathbb{Z^+},$ 
$\;(p_{nk},q_{nk}) = (P_k, Q_k).$

**Proof:**

In general, continued fraction results may have to adjust to the first element 
in $\;\alpha = [a_1, a_2, \cdots]$ being $a_1,$ rather than $a_0.$ 
When $\;n=1\;$ (i.e. $\;\sqrt{2} = [1,\overline{2}]),\;$ the artificial nature 
        of 
$\;(p_{n-1}, q_{n-1}) = (p_0, q_0) = (1,0)\;$ *suggests* that this case
should be handled separately.

$\underline{\text{case 1:} \;\; n>1}$

In [Old-s_pdf](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/Continued%20Fractions.pdf), the analysis in pages 114-115 (page 61/85 in the pdf file), 
establishes the following: 
(1) $\;p_{n-1} = Dq_n - a_1p_n\;$ and $\;q_{n-1} = p_n - a_1q_n.$ 
(2) $\;{p_n}^2 - D{q_n}^2 = (-1)^n.$

However, examination of this analysis indicates that it can be extended to

$\alpha_{[(nk)+1]} = \sqrt{D} + a_1\; :\;k\in\mathbb{Z^+} \;\Rightarrow\; 
\sqrt{D} = \dfrac{(\sqrt{D} + a_1)p_{nk} + p_{[(nk)-1]}}
    {(\sqrt{D} + a_1)q_{nk} + q_{[(nk)-1]}}\;$

This leads to 
(3) $\;p_{[(nk)-1]} = Dq_{nk} - a_1p_{nk}\;$ and $\;q_{[(nk)-1]} = p_{nk} - a_1q_{nk}.$

Also, since $\;p_{nk}q_{[(nk)-1]} - q_{nk}p_{[(nk)-1]} = (-1)^{nk},\;$ this leads to 
(4)  $\;{p_{nk}}^2 - D{q_{nk}}^2 = (-1)^{nk}.$

(5) $\;{P_k}^2 - D{Q_k}^2 \;=\; (P_k + Q_k\sqrt{D})(P_k - Q_k\sqrt{D})
    \;=\; (P_1 + Q_1\sqrt{D})^k (P_1 - Q_1\sqrt{D})^k\;$ 
[since conjugation is multiplicitive]
$\;=\; (p_n + q_n\sqrt{D})^k (p_n - q_n\sqrt{D})^k
    \;=\; ({p_n}^2 - D{q_n}^2)^k \;=\; (-1)^{nk}
    \;=\; {p_{nk}}^2 - D{q_{nk}}^2.$

(6) Suppose that $\;\frac{p_{nk}}{q_{nk}} =\;$
*the ratio* $\;\frac{P_k}{Q_k}.$ 
Then, since $\;p_{nk}, q_{nk}, P_k,\;$ and $\;Q_k$ are all positive, 
$\exists s>0 \ni (p_{nk}, q_{nk}) = (sP_k, sQ_k) \;\Rightarrow\;
{p_{nk}}^2 - D{q_{nk}}^2 = s^2({P_k}^2 - D{Q_k}^2).$ 
Therefore, by result (5), $\;(p_{nk}, q_{nk}) = (P_k, Q_k).$

..........................

Let $A$ denote the continued fraction 
        $\;[a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n] = \frac{p_n}{q_n}.$ 
Let $B$ denote the continued fraction $\;[2a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n].$ 
 
Then, $\;B = a_1 + \frac{p_n}{q_n}\;$ and 
 
$\;\frac{p_{2n}}{q_{2n}} = \;$ the continued fraction represented by 
        $\;[A, B].$

Therefore, 
$\;\dfrac{Bp_n + p_{n-1}}{Bq_n + q_{n-1}} = \;$ 
        the *ratio* $\;\dfrac{p_{2n}}{q_{2n}}.$

By the previous results, this leads to

$\dfrac{p_{2n}}{q_{2n}} \;=\; \dfrac{(a_1 + \frac{p_n}{q_n})p_n + (Dq_n - a_1p_n)}
    {{(a_1 + \frac{p_n}{q_n})q_n + (p_n - a_1q_n)}}
\;=\; \dfrac{a_1p_n + \frac{{p_n}^2}{q_n} + Dq_n - a_1p_n}
{a_1q_n + p_n + p_n - a_1q_n} $

$=\; \dfrac{{p_n}^2 + D{q_n}^2}{2p_nq_n} \;=\; \dfrac{P_2}{Q_2}.\;$
Therefore, by result (6), $\;(p_{2n}, q_{2n}) = (P_2, Q_2).$

(7) Thus, when $n>1,$ the conjecture is true for $k=2.$

..........................

Inductively assume that when $n>1,$ the conjecture is true for 
        $\;\{1, 2, \cdots, k\}.$

$P_{k+1} + \sqrt{D}Q_{k+1} \;=\; (P_k + \sqrt{D}Q_k)(P_1 + \sqrt{D}Q_1)$

$=\; (P_kP_1 + DQ_kQ_1) + \sqrt{D}(P_kQ_1 + P_1Q_k)$

$=\;$ [by inductive assumption] 
$\;(p_{nk}p_n + Dq_{nk}q_n) + \sqrt{D}(p_{nk}q_n + p_nq_{nk}) \;\Rightarrow$

$(P_{k+1},Q_{k+1}) \;=\; (p_{nk}p_n + Dq_{nk}q_n, p_{nk}q_n + p_nq_{nk}).$

Let $C$ denote the continued fraction representation of $\;\dfrac{p_{nk}}{q_{nk}}.$

Then $\;\dfrac{p_{[n(k+1)]}}{q_{[n(k+1)]}} = \;$ the continued fraction represented by 
        $\;[C, B].$

Therefore, 
$\;\dfrac{Bp_{nk} + p_{[(nk)-1]}}{Bq_{nk} + q_{[(nk)-1]}} = \;$ 
        the *ratio* $\;\dfrac{p_{[n(k+1)]}}{q_{[n(k+1)]}}.$

By the previous results, this leads to

$\dfrac{p_{[n(k+1)]}}{q_{[n(k+1)]}} \;=\; 
\dfrac{(a_1 + \frac{p_n}{q_n})p_{nk} + (Dq_{nk} - a_1p_{nk})}
    {(a_1 + \frac{p_{n}}{q_n})q_{nk} + (p_{nk} - a_1q_{nk})}
\;=\; \dfrac{a_1p_{nk} + \frac{p_np_{nk}}{q_n} + Dq_{nk} - a_1p_{nk}}
{a_1q_{nk} + \frac{p_nq_{nk}}{q_n} + p_{nk} - a_1q_{nk}}$

$=\; \dfrac{p_np_{nk} + Dq_{nk}q_n}{p_nq_{nk} + p_{nk}{q_n}}
\;=\; \dfrac{P_{k+1}}{Q_{k+1}}.\;$

Therefore, by result (6), $\;(p_{[n(k+1)]}, q_{[n(k+1)]}) = (P_{k+1}, Q_{k+1}).$

(8) Thus, when $n>1,$ the conjecture is true by induction.

..........................

$\underline{\text{case 2:} \;\; n=1}$

When $n=1, \;\sqrt{D} = [a_1, \overline{2a_1}].$

(9) Therefore, $\;(p_1, q_1) = (a_1, 1), \;(p_2, q_2) = (2{a_1}^2 + 1, 2a_1),\;$ 
and for $\;2\leq k \in\mathbb{Z^+}, \;(p_{k+1}, q_{k+1})
\;=\; (2a_1p_k + p_{k-1}, 2a_1q_k + q_{k-1}).$

$\sqrt{D} + a_1 = [\overline{2a_1}] \;=\; 2a_1 + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{D} + a_1} \;\Rightarrow$

$D + {a_1}^2 + 2a_1\sqrt{D} = 2a_1\sqrt{D} + 2{a_1}^2 + 1 \;\Rightarrow\;$

(10) $\;D = {a_1}^2 +1.$

(11) From (9) and (10), $\;{p_1}^2 - D{q_1}^2 = -1.$

..........................

Let $R$ represent the continued fraction $\;[a_1, 2a_1, \cdots, 2a_1]\; ([k+1] $ elements). 
This implies that $\;R = \frac{p_{k+1}}{q_{k+1}}.$ 
Let $\;S = \;$ the continued fraction represented by $\;[\overline{2a_1}] \;\Rightarrow S = a_1 + \sqrt{D}.$ 
Then $\sqrt{D} = \;$ the continued fraction represented by $\;[R, S].$

(12) Therefore, $\;\sqrt{D} \;=\; \dfrac{Sp_{k+1} + p_k}{Sq_{k+1} + q_k}.$

This is very similar to equation (4.39) given in [Old-s_pdf](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/Continued%20Fractions.pdf), on page 114 
(page 61/85 in the pdf file).  That pdf's subsequent analysis will be paralleled 
with result (12) above as the starting point and will lead to :

(13) When $n=1,\;$ and $\;k\geq 2:$ 
$p_k = Dq_{k+1} - a_1p_{k+1} \;$ and $\;q_k = p_{k+1} - a_1q_{k+1}.$

(14) Continuing the parallel analysis, result (13) will lead to 
${p_k}^2 - D(q_k)^2 = (-1)^k.$

(15) The analysis and conclusions in results (5) and (6) from case 1 also 
apply when $n=1.\;$  Therefore, 
$\;{P_k}^2 - D{Q_k}^2 = (-1)^k = {p_k}^2 - D(q_k)^2.$ 
Therefore, $\;\frac{p_k}{q_k} = \frac{P_k}{Q_k} \;\Rightarrow\;
(p_k, q_k) = (P_k, Q_k).$

..........................

(16) From results (9) and (10) above, it is immediate that 
$(p_2, q_2) = (2{a_1}^2 + 1, 2a_1) = ({a_1}^2 + D, 2a_1) = (P_2, Q_2).$

Inductively assume that when $n=1,\;$ the conjecture is true for 
$\;\{1, 2, \cdots, (k+1)\}.$

$P_{k+2} + \sqrt{D}Q_{k+2} \;=\; (P_{k+1} + \sqrt{D}Q_{k+1})(P_1 + \sqrt{D}Q_1)$

$=\; (P_{k+1}P_1 + DQ_{k+1}Q_1) + \sqrt{D}(P_{k+1}Q_1 + P_1Q_{k+1})$

$=\;$ [by inductive assumption] 
$\;(p_{k+1}a_1 + Dq_{k+1}) + \sqrt{D}(p_{k+1} + a_1q_{k+1}) \;\Rightarrow$

$(P_{k+2},Q_{k+2}) \;=\; (p_{k+1}a_1 + Dq_{k+1}, p_{k+1} + a_1q_{k+1}).$

..........................

Let $T$ denote the continued fraction representation of $\;\dfrac{p_{k+1}}{q_{k+1}}.$

Then $\;\dfrac{p_{k+2}}{q_{k+2}} = \;$ the continued fraction represented by 
        $\;[T, 2a_1].$

Therefore, 
$\;\dfrac{2a_1p_{k+1} + p_k}{2a_1q_{k+1} + q_k} = \;$ 
        the *ratio* $\;\dfrac{p_{k+2}}{q_{k+2}}.$

Using result (13), this leads to

$\dfrac{p_{k+2}}{q_{k+2}} \;=\; 
\dfrac{2a_1p_{k+1} + (Dq_{k+1} - a_1p_{k+1})}{2a_1q_{k+1} + (p_{k+1} - a_1q_{k+1})}
\;=\; \dfrac{a_1p_{k+1} + Dq_{k+1}}
{a_1q_{k+1} + p_{k+1}}
\;=\; \dfrac{P_{k+2}}{Q_{k+2}}.\;$

Therefore, by result (15), $\;(p_{k+2}, q_{k+2}) = (P_{k+2}, Q_{k+2}).$

(17) Thus, when $n=1,$ the conjecture is also true by induction.