# $d \in \mathbb{N}$, that is not a square, show that the continued fractions for following numbers are purely periodic

Tags: prime-numbers, continued-fractions

> Let $d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d$ not a square number. Now show
>   that the continued fractions for $\sqrt{d} + \lfloor\sqrt{d}\rfloor$
>   and $\frac{1}{(\sqrt{d} - \lfloor\sqrt{d}\rfloor)}$ are purely
>   periodic.
>
> Furthermore, show that there exists $m \in N$ so that $\sqrt{d}$ is
>   periodic from the second number, i.e. $[a_0$; $\overline
> > {a_1a_2,...,a_m}]$ .

I tried to solve this, but I do not have an idea where to start.
Some of my attempts:

$1)$ For *irrational* number a of a degree $2$, and assuming $a'$ is the other root of the minimal polynomial of $a$, that $-1 < a' < 0$.

$~~1.1)$ Define following series $x_n$ for $a =[a_0$; ${a_1,a_2,...}$], then, $x_{n+1}$ is the real number such that  $a =[a_0$; ${a_1,a_2,..., x_{n+1}}$] and that $x_n$ = $a_n$ + $\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}$.

$~~1.2)$ Show that for any $n \in\mathbb{N}$, $-1 < x_{n+1} < 0$ and that $a_n=\lfloor$$\frac{-1}{x_{n+1}}$$\rfloor$.

I've shown $1.1$ and $1.2$

Thank you.

Comment: Here, we ask that you show your efforts and thoughts.  Do not merely ask us to do it for you.

Comment: What book or notes are you using? Both your questions are standard results, this one has a pretty long answer, not really suitable for online

Comment: @WillJagy Hi, I'm using following book [link](https://archive.org/stream/AnIntroductionToTheTheoryOfNumbers-4thEd-G.h.HardyE.m.Wright#page/n1). Where can I find said results?

Comment: @MicroT  See the **My research** section of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749487/algebra-direct-connect-pell-eqn-soln-p-nk-q-nk-with-p-n-q-n-sqrtd.  It shows the 4 continued fraction references that I have found helpful.  As suggested by Will Jagy's comment, it is better to find and explore good continued fraction references, than to attempt to derive results yourself.