# Why continued fraction gives initial solution of Pell's equation

Tags: diophantine-equations, continued-fractions, pell-type-equations

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Fundamental_solution_via_continued_fractions), following algorithm find the smallest solution of $x^2-dy^2=1$. How the validity of this algorithm is shown?

1. Let $α_0 :=\sqrt{d}$.
2. Let $q_i:= ⌊α_i⌋$, $α_{i+1} := 1/(αi − qi)$ and construct the infinite series. Such series always have finite period.
3. Let the series above $q_0, q_1, \ldots , q_{m−1}, q_m , q_1, \ldots$. The period is $m-1$. Let $b:=[q_0; q_1, \ldots , q_{m−1}]=q_0+\frac{1}{q_1+\frac{1}{\ldots+q_{m-1}}}$
4. Let $b:=x/y$ (x and y are coprime). Then, $x^2-dy^2=\pm1$.
   If $x^2-dy^2=1$, output $\langle x,y\rangle$. Otherwise, output $\langle x^2+dy^2,2xy\rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no quick answer to that, you have to study continued fractions.  A starting point would be the 4 online pdf-s that I referred to in this query: [algebra direct connect pell eqn soln $(p_{nk},q_{nk})$ with $(p_n + q_n\sqrt{D})^k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749487/algebra-direct-connect-pell-eqn-soln-p-nk-q-nk-with-p-n-q-n-sqrtd/2752161#2752161)