# In which base $b$ is $(374)_b$ a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

If you convert this number to base 10, we can obtain the expression $$3b^2+7b+4 = (b+1)(3b+4).$$
Since $\gcd(b+1,3b+4) = 1$, we further conclude that both $b+1$ and $3b+4$ are perfect squares.

So the problem is equivalent to finding $b$ that satisfies the Diophantine equation $$3(b+1)^2+1 = L^2,$$ where $\gcd(b+1,L) = 1$.

I'm not sure how to find all solutions to the above equation.

Comment: $n^2-3m^2=1$ is an instance of [Pell's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).

Answer (score 4):

You're off to a good start; if $b+1$ and $3b+4$ are both perfect squares, then
$$3b+4=x^2\qquad\text{ and }\qquad b+1=y^2,$$
for some integers $x$ and $y$, and hence
$$x^2-3y^2=1.$$
This is a [Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation), and its solutions are well known. I suggest to start from the Wikipedia page to understand how to find all integral solutions. In particular there are infinitely many solutions.

One characterization of the integral solutions is that they are precisely the pairs of integers $(x,y)$ for which
$$x+y\sqrt{3}=\pm(2+\sqrt{3})^k,$$
for some integer $k$. Of course the choice of $\pm$ sign only changes the signs of $x$ and $y$, and the same is true if we replace $k$ by $-k$. So to find all solutions $b$ it suffices to consider $(2+\sqrt{3})^k$ with $k\geq0$. The first few solutions are:

$$\begin{array}{r|rr|rr}
k&x&y&b&(374)_b\\
\hline
0&1&0&\color{red}{-1}&\color{red}{0^2}\\
1&2&1&\color{red}{0}&\color{red}{2^2}\\
2&7&4&15&28^2\\
3&26&15&224&390^2\\
4&97&56&3135&5432^2\\
5&362&209&43680&75658^2
\end{array}$$

Comment: any good resources to study how to find solutions of Pell's equations

Comment: @KartikBhatia [This paper](http://www.ams.org/notices/200202/fea-lenstra.pdf) gives a nice introduction.

Comment: With respect to the following link, I recommend the 4 online sources referred to in the query.  As far as the question and answer given in the query (both by me), I regard them as a bit much for someone new to the topic:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749487/algebra-direct-connect-pell-eqn-soln-p-nk-q-nk-with-p-n-q-n-sqrtd

Comment: $$  x_{n+2} = 4 x_{n+1} - x_n  $$   and  $$  y_{n+2} = 4 y_{n+1} - y_n  $$