# I'm trying to calculate the Probability of a Full House hand, where 7 cards are drawn and the deck is less than its maximum size.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poker

Frankly I've seen questions similar to this answered on this site but they don't paint a clear enough image. Though I must confess that I'm a total novice to probability and combinatorics so I might just be stupid.

I have attempted to calculate, at what point is a Full House 100% probable in 7 card poker by reducing the number of cards in the deck. However the answer I recieved by folowing the formulas I've been providded with, produced results which seem incorect.

To my understanding to calculate Full House we use three diferent formulas added together to account for all posible combinations.

Those are:
Two Three of a kinds and a single [3 3 1]
$\binom{13}2$$\binom{4}3^2$$\binom{11}1$$\binom{4}1$

Three of a kind and Two pairs [3 2 2]
$\binom{13}2$$\binom{4}3$$\binom{12}2$$\binom{4}2^2$

Three of a kind, a pair, and two singles [3 2 1 1]
$\binom{13}2$$\binom{4}3$$\binom{12}2$$\binom{4}2$$\binom{11}2$$\binom{4}1^2$

Of course the next step is to compute, then divide by $\binom{52}7$ and get the answer.
But if we start reducing the number of cards in the deck, the numbers produced start getting weird.

For example let's say we have the cards:
5, 6, 9, 10, K, A of Spades
2, 7, 10, J, K of Hearts
2, 5, 6, 7, 10, J, Q, A of Diamonds
4, 5, 6, 9, J of Clubs

This means the deck has:
4 suits
11 ranks
9 pairs
4 Three of a kinds
...and over all 24 cards to chose from.

The issue is, that in this scenario the probability given by the formula is 1.33472 or 133%.
Of this [3 3 1] is equal to 0.9985%
[3 2 2] is 4.6599%
and [3 2 1 1] is 127.8136%

These numbers or at least the third one obviously does not look right. However as the novice I am to probability and combinatorics I can't see just where I'm going wrong.

Is there a diferent technique I should be using, or is there some sort of diference I'm not accounting for?
I'd love to understand.

Comment: Seems like you have a flaw in your *work-flow* strategy.  Rather than attacking a difficult probability problem, without training, I suggest that you try to find the right probability book for you, a book with many exercises for you to solve, open the book to page 1, and attack.  This comment represents a hard-won lesson, where I (more than once) tried to walk before I could crawl.  I (for example) spent weeks developing a theorem that turned out to be an elementary result.  If I had found the right book, in advance, I would have avoided the wasted time and frustration.

Comment: @user2661923 what theorem was it, just by curiosity ?

Comment: @Kilkik I was trying to prove that all solutions to the diophantine $~X^2 - 2Y^2 = 1 ~: ~X,Y \in \Bbb{Z^+}~$ are given by $$(P_k,Q_k) ~: ~k \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~\text{where} ~\left( ~3 + 2\sqrt{2} ~\right)^k = \left(P_k + Q_k\sqrt{2} ~\right).$$  ...see next comment

Comment: @Kilkik Upon advice received at MathSE, on other peripherally related math questions, I consulted chapter 1 (**only**) of [this book](https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-497500429547.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/a06_cont_frac_Khinchin.pdf) as well as [this entire book](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/Continued%20Fractions.pdf).

Comment: @Kilkik Subsequently, researching on the internet, I found an **indirect proof** of the more general premise.  This left me unsatisfied; I wanted to find a direct algebraic proof.  The Old-s pdf (2nd link in previous comment) led to such a proof.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749487/algebra-direct-connect-pell-eqn-soln-p-nk-q-nk-with-p-n-q-n-sqrtd), where I posted the question.  Consulting the Old-s pdf allowed me to find the desired proof, and present it as an answer to my own question.  I wouldn't have found the direct proof without consulting the Old-s pdf.